Is it OK to say "he dare challenge me?"
I just want to ask a question regarding the usage of the word "dare".
Let's say for example that I am going to use it as a modal verb and in my modal construction, I would write: "He dare challenge me?" Is this correct?
I know that some of you guys would say "dare he challenge me?" Is more correct. However, I still would like to know if my example is correct.

It's rare, but good English.

That older form is an expression of mocking incredulity. Surely it can't be true that he is challenging me. What audacity!

I don't recognize it as even "valid" English let alone "good" English. I'd accept He dares challenge me as just about "valid" (where He dares to challenge me is better). Also How dare he challenge me! as an exclamatory rhetorical question. But I'm not aware of any time or dialect where He dare challenge me is or ever was an acceptable verb form.

But in the phrase "he dares to challenge me" Doesn't the word "dare" act as a main verb?

Even modal verbs should agree in person and number with their subjects. Most, like "can," "would," etc. don't change their form with conjugations, but "dare" does. "I dare," "he dares." So no, it should be "He dares challenge me?"
Now, I wouldn't advise worrying about it too much. First of all, "dare" just isn't that common at all in contemporary English, especially as a modal. Where it is, it would be more common to add "to," "He dares to challenge me." And it's much more common as a statement than a question. And where we want a question, "how dare he" is much more common.
For some reason, all this usage varies by the person of the subject. That is, it's a first-person "dare" question, with "dare" fronted, is still a bit old-fashioned or intentionally arch but comparatively common enough: "Dare I ask why?" But the third-person equivalent just doesn't happen often.

It's probably technically correct, but you're unlikely to ever hear anybody say:

He dare challenge me?

However, you might hear someone say:

How dare he challenge me!

At least in spoken American English.

I think it's not technically correct; I'll add an answer.
